# How to put a SVG Content into a new SVG file via PyCairo

Tags: python, svg, import, pycairo

i tried so many things, but nothing worked.
So the question is easy:
How does it work?
I got several SVG files and I want to create a new SVG file and "import" the content of the other files an place them on specific coordinates.

While searching for help, I realized, that maybe PyCairo is just not able to do it. In this case: is there any other Python way to do it?

Thanks a lot !